# chrome storage api not saving passed data

Tags: google-chrome, vue.js, google-chrome-extension

I have this code:

```
    bookmarkProfile() {
      var username = this.unsername
      var userData = {
        profileInfo: this.userInfo,
        profileMedia: this.igFeed
      }
      browser.storage.local.set({username: userData})
        console.log('Profile saved')
    }
// this is what I use to get all the data
        getWatchedProfiles() {
            browser.storage.local.get(null, (items) => {
                console.log(items)
            })
        }
```

What I expect is that the passed data are saved using the chrome storage api, but if I inspect the storage I will not see any data. I'm trying to implement this inside a chrome extension to store some users data fetched using ajax. Is there any error or a fix ?

Comment: 1) `{username: userData}` should be `{[username]: userData}`, 2) The API is asynchronous so you should read a value in the callback of the write call.

Comment: I was setting a callback in the `chrome.storage.local.set()` function, but I was getting an error. I need to try your suggestion.

Comment: @wOxxOm tested the code with the change you suggested but data still not saved

Comment: Check the possible typo in `this.unsername`.

Comment: there is no probem with that variable, I've added a callback to the set function and I'm able to see the value, but inside the application tab on localstorage voice, there's no data.

Comment: I've finally found a way to make the things working. Now I just need to get the data from background.js script, I didn't know that the storage.local wasn't accessible from my vue instance, so I will implement messaging to get the data when needed